# WPF font size not changing

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a "Hello World" in WPF. Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello, WPF" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="60" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"/>

</Grid>
```

...and my code-behind:

```
 private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.FontSize = 90;
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.FontSize = 72;
    }
```

When I MouseOver the TextBlock, the font should be set to the larger size, and on MouseLeave it should be set to the smaller size.

However, the font size is unchanged. The handler is called successfully, so why did the font size not change?

Comment: Instead of `this` use `TextBlock` name.

Comment: @lkw trigger is best solution for this

Comment: @LkW If any answer help you, check that for correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Name your `TextBlock` and affect the new `FontSize` to it

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="Tb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello, WPF" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="60" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"/>        
</Grid>
```

and the code behind

```
  private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Tb.FontSize = 90;
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Tb.FontSize = 72;
    }
```

**Better solution**

and a better solution to do that is by using a Trigger, no event handler is required

```
<TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello, WPF" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="90"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="72"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

You must get textBlock from object like this. In this case you don't need name for TextBlock.

```
private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       var block = sender as TextBlock;
       block.FontSize = 90;
    }

private void TextBlock_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      var block = sender as TextBlock;
      block.FontSize = 72;
    }
```